# wpf extend contextmenu of textbox

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, extend

I am searching for a way to extend the contextmenu of a textbox. I know there are dozens of solutions out there that recreate the contextmenu as a whole, but how on earth can I simply add one custom entry to a existing context menu?

Thanks
Klaus

Comment: I believe you can do only by using Win32 API calls. TextBox relies on the native input library of Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 <TextBox>
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll" />
           //Your own item here
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
```

Please not that all command are automatically operation and will work as expected

Comment: I asked because I like to have a completely dynamic contextmenu (unknown number of root and child entries) - so how can I influence the menu if this is the case?

Comment: Found it: you can handle ContextMenuOpeing like shown herer:

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb613568(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1